# Wordpress: call php file?

Tags: php, wordpress

basically I need to use the scripts at verify.php. however when I navigate to mysite.com/verify.php, wordpress page shows up and throws 404.

I need to send AJAX post to this file from jQuery in the main wordpress index page.

As well as in the future I will have some more somescript.php to load via URL and I need wordpress to not throw 404.

Comment: What's your specific programming question? Also, what have you tried?

Comment: Please expand and provide more detail in your question, otherwise it's likely to get closed.

Comment: navigating to mysite.com/verify.php will not load the said php file but instead look for a wordpress page. the wordpress page doesn't exist and so it returns 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom page template. Within the custom page template you can include your own php code.

Answer (score 0):

Before anyone can answer your question, please verify what is "verify.php", is it a file that you upload to /[your-wordpress-folder]/ or a custom page template ?

maybe his will help you :

1. http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
2. http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates